# Can any one help me to decode Conditional(?) Operator in Derived Column of SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have to decode below expression in SQL query but very less familiar with SSIS ,so any body can help me to decode this expression.

```
D_UPDTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY =   CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY > 0 ? FINDSTRING(@[User::LV_LoadLogKey],LTRIM(RTRIM((DT_WSTR,35)CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY)),1) > 0 ? CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY : UPDTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY : UPDTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY
```

Comment: What about the expression don't you understand here? Then we can fill in the gaps. The above is just a couple of inline If statements and some basic string manipulation., so it's not the most complex (if I am honest).

Comment: How we can write in SQL using case or if ,There are 2 conditional operator(?) which confusing me ,if you know then can explain it only I can write in SQL but don't understand what it is (?) in the above expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what parts of the expression you don't understand, this answer is a little broad, but tells you what each part does. It'll then be up to you to put the information together.

Firstly let's look at this syntax:

```sh
{Boolean Expression} ? {Scalar Value} : {Scalar Value}
```

This, in SSIS, is an inline If. It's the equivilent of `IIF` in T-SQL (which is a short `CASE` expression). In simple terms the following expressions would be comparable:

```sh
SomeValue > Another Value ? 1 : 0
```

```sql
IIF(SomeValue > AnotherValue, 1, 0)
CASE WHEN SomeValue > AnotherValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

In your expression you have nested inline ifs, so in short hand looks like this:

```sh
{Boolean Expression 1} ? {Boolean Expression 2} ? {Scalar Value When 1 and 2 are true} : {Scalar Value when 1 is true, 2 is false} : {Scalar Value when 1 is false}
```

If it helps, here is a version with added parenthesis to help see where the inline ifs start and end:

```sh
({Boolean Expression 1} ? ({Boolean Expression 2} ? {Scalar Value When 1 and 2 are true} : {Scalar Value when 1 is true, 2 is false}) : {Scalar Value when 1 is false})
```

---

Now let's look at the second boolean expression:

```sh
FINDSTRING(@[User::LV_LoadLogKey],LTRIM(RTRIM((DT_WSTR,35)CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY)),1) > 0
```

Here you have several operators. Firstly `(DT_WSTR,35)` converts the following expression (in this case `CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY`) to a `DT_WSTR` of length 35. `DT_WSTR` is the equivilent to `nvarchar` in T-SQL. So this would be equivilent to `CONVERT(nvarchar(35),CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY)` or `CAST(CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY AS nvarchar(35))` in T-SQL.

`LTRIM` and `RTRIM` do the same as their T-SQL counterparts; they remove the leading and trailing whitespace characters from a string.

Finally you have `FINDSTRING`, which is equivilent to `CHARINDEX` in T-SQL. The only difference is that the first 2 parameters are reversed; the first parameter is the string to search for the character(s) *in*, and the second parameter the character(s) to search *for*. The third parameter is the same, the occurrence number. So for a simplified version of your `FINDSTRING` the following would be equivalent:

```sh
FINSTRING(@[User::LV_LoadLogKey],CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY,1)
```

```sql
CHARINDEX(CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY, @LV_LoadLogKey,1)
```

Comment: That means if CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY>0 AND FINDSTRING(@[User::LV_LoadLogKey],LTRIM(RTRIM((DT_WSTR,35)CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY)),1) > 0 THEN it would be CRCTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY else it be UPDTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY right?

Comment: Yes, @AjeetVerma . Why the developer used 2 nested inline ifs, rather than a logical AND (`&&`) and one inline if, I don't know though.

Comment: but @Larnu, why there are 2 times column UPDTD_LOAD_LOG_KEY mentioned in last of expression.

Comment: Because  you need a FALSE value for *both* inline ifs, @AjeetVerma . This is why I mentioned in the prior comment about my confusion the developer didn't use a logical AND and one inline if.